# DevOps Reference CSV File with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, azure-devops

I'm trying to create an NSG from a CSV file using PowerShell. In ISE it works fine, I think the issue is the way it calls the file, as I get the error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'D:\a\r1\a\CSV\test.csv'
PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

The script I have is a simple NSG create script:

```
$nsg  -ResourceGroupName test-rg -Location 'West Europe'

foreach($rule in  import-csv 'CSV\test.csv'){
$NSG | Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
-Name $rule.RuleName `
-Description $rule.Description `
-Priority $rule.Priority `
-Protocol $rule.Protocol `
-Access $rule.Access `
-Direction $rule.Direction `
-SourceAddressPrefix ($rule.SourceAddressPrefix -split ',') `
-DestinationAddressPrefix ($rule.DestinationAddressPrefix -split ',') `
-DestinationPortRange ($rule.DestinationPortRange -split ',') `
-SourcePortRange $rule.SourcePortRange 
}
$NSG | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Verbose
```

I've tried using

`'D:\a\r1\a\$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\CSV\test3.csv'` and `'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\CSV\test3.csv'` and  `'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/CSV/test3.csv'` and

`'.\CSV\test3.csv'` and `'./CSV/test3.csv'`

With no joy. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

I'm using an inline script in Azure DevOps.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Looking at the path in the error message, it seems that `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` is not expanded, probably due to you using single quotes. Try with double quotes: `"D:\a\r1\a\$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\CSV\test3.csv"`. You could also use `$env:BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY`. Personally, I would use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to get rid of those nasty backticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of your examples there, you're using single quotes, which have a special meaning.

In PowerShell , a single quote means "this is a string literal", as in "look in a directory which is literally called `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\CSV\`, which is probably causing you some grief.

In the only example without that syntax, you're using a relative path.  I would first off start by finding out how this `csv` file is getting onto the device and make sure that works.  You could modify the script to a simple `dir` to check and see what directory the script launches from.

```
#check to see which directory we're running from
Get-ChildItem
```

If you see the `.csv` file is there, like so:

```
 Directory: C:\temp\Preferences


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                  
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                  
d-----         5/17/2021   3:39 PM            350 test1.cv
```

Then modify your code to reference the absolute path:

```
$nsg  -ResourceGroupName test-rg -Location 'West Europe'
$rules = import-csv C:\temp\Preferences\test.csv

foreach($rule in $rules){
$NSG | Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
```

If this doesn't wholly solve the issue, it will get you closer to a solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I've tried and all I'm getting in the logs is `2021-07- The string is missing the terminator: ".
 At D:\a\_temp\a43df466-4ada-41fa-ae73-039d3de48488.ps1:42 char:32
+ foreach($rule in  import-csv ".\CSV\test3.csv"){
 +                                ~
Missing property name after reference operator.
  + CategoryInfo   : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString`

Comment: Modify your `Foreach` loop like I'm showing in my example.  You want to break those two steps for legibility and also to see where your code is actually failing.